# 2 versions of LibPCRE; Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, octave, pcre

I've recently upgraded to Octave 3.6.4, and am suddenly having a problem where I get the message `(octave:23508): GLib-CRITICAL **: PCRE library is compiled without UTF8 support`
.  A simple test of `pcretest -C` gives me

```
PCRE version 8.21 2011-12-12
Compiled with
No UTF-8 support
No Unicode properties support
No just-in-time compiler support
Newline sequence is LF
\R matches all Unicode newlines
Internal link size = 2
POSIX malloc threshold = 10
Default match limit = 10000000
Default recursion depth limit = 10000000
Match recursion uses stack
```

After research, I downloaded the source and recompiled (using these directions: )[enter link description here](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/pcre.html).  Now, I have two versions of libpcre on my system. The previous 8.21 in `/usr/local/bin/pcretest`, and the new 8.33 in `/usr/bin/pcretest`.  This latter is the one I want, as it gives

```
ahowe42@Neuromancer:~/Downloads$ /usr/bin/pcretest -C
PCRE version 8.33 2013-05-28
Compiled with
8-bit support
UTF-8 support
16-bit support
UTF-16 support
32-bit support
UTF-32 support
Unicode properties support
No just-in-time compiler support
Newline sequence is LF
\R matches all Unicode newlines
Internal link size = 2
POSIX malloc threshold = 10
Default match limit = 10000000
Default recursion depth limit = 10000000
Match recursion uses stack
```

However, running pcretest without the path is still using the old one, as is Octave. How can I remove ver 8.21 and/or force the system to use 8.33?

Comment: Update: I removed the offending versions of pcretest and pcregrep from `/usr/local/bin` and replaced them with symlinks to the 8.33 versions in `/usr/bin`.  This solved the issue of calling pcretest from the console and not getting 8.33; but the Octave error persists.

Comment: Are you compiling Octave?  I am also on Ubuntu 12.04.  I didn't need a special version.
Here's a list of everything I needed to compile Octave (starting on a fresh EC2 instance with nothing installed yet).  Maybe one of these will fix your problem:

Comment: gcc g++ gfortran libpcre3-dev libblas-dev liblapack-dev libqt4-opengl-dev libreadline6-dev libqhull-dev libfftw3-dev libglpk-dev libsuitesparse-dev libarpack++2-dev libgraphicsmagick++1-dev libqrupdate-dev flex bison gnuplot gperf ghostscript libfontconfig1-dev libfltk1.1-dev texinfo libqscintilla2-dev pstoedit epstool transfig texlive autoconf automake make openjdk-6-jdk libcurl4-openssl-dev libhdf5-serial-dev

Comment: Yes, I downloaded 3.6 from sourceforge and compiled myself, since the Ubuntu repository still has a really old version.  I already have all those.  This is the only issue I have.

Comment: Someone on the Octave mailing list is saying it's an issue not with Octave, but with how GLib is compiled.  So now the question becomes: how can I compile GLib with PCRE 8.33 UTF8 support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solved this.  After updating libpcre and remapping the system to use 8.33, I just needed to recompile Octave.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when migrating on Mac OS X from an older XAMPP Version to the latest one. There MariaDB seems now to be used instead of the Mysql DB.

When I entered pcretest -C on a Terminal I got

PCRE version 8.37 2015-04-28
Compiled with
  8-bit support
  UTF-8 support
  16-bit support
  UTF-16 support
  32-bit support
  UTF-32 support
...

so I couldn't see the reason for this message. But when I looked into the XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin directory I saw that here also binaries starting with pcre were present. Also in the XAMM/xamppfiles/lib directory were files starting with pcre.

So my (I admit dirty) solution was to copy all pcre* files from /opt/local/bin/ and /opt/local/lib/ to /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin and lib.

After a restart of mysql the error did not show up any more.